# Is there a way to combine multiple powerbi api requests in to a single restapi call? Something like a batch request to get a collective response?

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi

I'm trying to reduce the api calls to fetch data out of powerbi rest api. when i call endpoint like /Groups, The response is straight forward in a single api call, I get all the groups. in order to get datasets,dashboards and reports i'll have to pass every group id to endpoints of reports,datasets.,etc.

eg. 
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets

Is there a way to combine these requests, such a way that i send multiple group ids in a single api call to get all the datasets from their respective groups?

I have not found a way to combine it all together to make a single batch api call.

However, I tried a different endpoint found from MSDocs to avoid input of group id.

GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets

But the problem with this is, the response wont have information of which group the dataset belongs to. without group information,the retrieved data wont be useful for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin) part of the API. To get a list of all groups in your organization, call [GetGroupsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups_getgroupsasadmin) (you can filter what you want to get too). Similarly, call [GetDatasetsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets_getdatasetsasadmin) to get list of datasets. Look at their [`webUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets_getdatasetsasadmin#dataset) property to find their group.

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets` wont return all datasets (or datasets from multiple groups) but will give you the datasets located in your own `My workspace`.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I was aware of that. my question is more like.

how can i pass multiple ids in a single api call.. like
`
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group 1}/datasets

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group 2}/datasets
`

is it possible to send both group1 and group2 in a single api call. something like a batch request or something. so in a single response i get results of multiple groups.

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you can provide a meaningful filter in the admin call, use it. Otherwise you need to call the API multiple times